# How to attach a progress bar as a border to div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

In `reactjs` I need to attach a linear progress bar as a bottom to `div`. I tried with a normal linear progress bar and attached the linear progress to the end of the `div` with the `flex-end` property.

Below is the code sandbox link for my implementation.

Code Sandbox Link:
[codesandbox.io/s/linear-progress-bar-forked-udhxqz](https://codesandbox.io/s/linear-progress-bar-forked-udhxqz)

But my requirement is the `div` should be as per the below screenshot
[image: SCREENSHOT WITH BORDER DIV].

How can I achieve the below `div` with `HTML` and `CSS` changes?

I should implement using in `reactjs`

Comment: Is there any reason that it has to be a *border*, or would simply having it at the bottom of the div and appearing to be a border work?

Comment: It should simply be at the bottom not mandatorily as a border.But the look and feel should be like its attached with border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your example working with a few CSS changes, below are the only two parts I needed to change:

```css
.App {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.emptyProgressBar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.fillingProgressBar {
  width: 102%;
}
```

Then in `App.tsx`, change your left style to `-101`, like the following:

```
left: props.percent - 101 + "%",
```

A working example forked from your sandbox is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/linear-progress-bar-forked-hgv7kq?file=/src/styles.css).

Comment: The solution is fine for the ends of div .Is it possible to adjust the filled part to look as border ends of the div.

I tried adjusting the border-radius of the filled part but was unable to achieve

Comment: @Hackerrocker1169 does my edit answer your question? Should be live at the same link as well.

Comment: /* If you want the progress bar to be flush with the end of the div: */
.fillingProgressBar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}


With this the filled part progress bar is becoming straight vertical is it possible to make it slightly slanting as its in screenshot please

Comment: @Hackerrocker1169 updated the answer and example again